# How can I create non numeric metric on Superset chart?

Tags: metrics, apache-superset, timeserieschart

How can I create non numeric metric on Superset chart ? for example:

[image: example chart]

I tried to Create custom metric like this:

[image: case when metric]

it didn't work:

[image: error]